# Access List of Available Types from a Visual Studio Add In?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, add-in, visual-studio-addins

Is there a way to access the types (Classes, Interfaces, etc., and their meta data) that are available inside the loaded projects within a solution in Visual Studio?

To be more specific, I'm attempting to develop a simple Visual Studio Add In to provide "Go To Implementation" functionality:

https://bitbucket.org/jbubriski/go-to-implementation/

**I realize that this exists in other productivity Add Ins/Extensions, but I'm making a bare bones one so I don't have to deal with slow downs, hangs, and crashes from other added "features".**

If you look at the source, I'm able to get the currently selected text using a very basic and fragile method.  Given the selection, I basically assume that it is an interface, strip off the 'I', and do a Solution-wide search for `ProjectItems` where the file name ends in `"\TypeName.cs"`.

Is there some internal list of types that Visual Studio maintains for intellisense that I have access to?  It would be nice to say:

```
var vsType = VS.GetLocalType("TypeName")
```

Then access

```
vsType.FileName
```

One step further would be

```
foreach(var vsType in VS.GetlocalTypes())
{
    if(vsType.Implements.Contains("IInterfaceName"))
    {
        // Found something that implements my interface!
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about native VS addons implementation, but if you are using DevExpress.CodeRush, goto definition functionality should be based on current position in source file, and do something like this to retrieve reference to declaring type:
`((TypeReferenceExpression)CodeRush.Source.Active).GetDeclaringType()`

P.S. I understand that I didn't answer on yor question, but hope this will give you a direction to search a solution

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, this doesn't really help me since I don't have their source code :P

Comment: FYI, I double checked and it looks like `TypeReferenceExpression` is a CodeRush class.

Answer (score 1):

More details later, if I get time, but see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.ityperesolutionservice.aspx.

Comment: I initially tried this, but I don't think it will work because I'm trying to reference types and interfaces that aren't actually compiled yet!  Let alone the fact that their not added to VS ass references.  Although, I could be missing something entirely.  If there is a way, I would appreciate more details.  Thanks!

Comment: So I guess intellisense is entirely internal?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Intellisense displays type members for existing types. You can get Intellisense for a local variable before the local is compiled, but the type of the variable must already exist.

Comment: Right, the types exist in the project, solution, or compiled .NET assemblies referenced by the project.  Visual Studio must maintain a list of the types available for use with Intellisense.  Can I tap into that list of types inside my add on?